# How to change function parameter type dynamically in go

Tags: go

I have a program as below. I am trying to change the type of a function argument dynamically as another library I am using requires passing `myMethod` signature with concrete type instead of that interface to do proper unmarshalling. Is that even possible in Go to dynamically make a function or anonymous function with argument's type generated dynamically or perhaps change the parameter type of a function?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type MyType interface {
    doThis()
}

type MyType1 struct{}

func (m MyType1) doThis() {
    fmt.Println("Type1 doThis")
}

type MyType2 struct{}

func (m MyType2) doThis() {
    fmt.Println("Type2 doThis")
}

func myMethod(myType MyType) {
    myType.doThis()
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    var type1 MyType
    type1 = &MyType1{}
    type1Val := reflect.TypeOf(type1)
    // TODO - change myMethod signature dynamically to accept type1Val as the type
}
```

Here is the GoPlay [link](https://play.golang.org/p/ZZsIOSJP-ON)

**Edit:** Adding clarification

The library I am using exposes a `registerSomething(someFunc)` where the input argument type of `someFunc` will be later used in some unmarshaling. If the input argument type is an interface, the unmarshal will return a map. If its a typed struct, the unmarshal will return the typed struct with all params populated correctly so I don't have to deal with unmarshaling.

Comment: "Is that even possible in Go to dynamically ..." In a word: No.

Comment: "requires passing myMethod signature with concrete type instead of that interface to do proper unmarshalling" This doesn't make sense to me. What do you mean by "passing myMethod signature"? Concrete types are not required for unmarshalling. In fact, all unmarshal functions in the standard library take an empty interface as argument.

Comment: `MyType1` and `MyType2` values can be passed to `myMethod` as is: `myMethod(MyType1{}); myMethod(MyType2{})`.  Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: @ThunderCat. I want the signature of `myMethod(MyType)` to be changed to `myMethod(MyType1)` in runtime. I am ok to make a new function if that is a possibility.

Comment: Write and use a simple wrapper? `func myMethod2(v MyType1) { myMethod(v) }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to change function parameter type dynamically in go [?]

You simply cannot. Go is statically typed.

(Making your code run is trivial, but probably not what you want:

```
type1Val := reflect.ValueOf(type1)
myMethod(*(type1Val.Interface().(*MyType1)))
```

and I have to admit I do not understand what you are trying to do with reflect here.)

Comment: I started playing with reflections to see if I can use `MakeFunc` to achieve what I am trying. @ThunderCat. I want the signature of `myMethod(MyType)` to be changed to `myMethod(MyType1)` or create a new function with signature `fn(MyType1)` in runtime.

Comment: @TechCrunch You cannot change a method signature, not even with reflection.